# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str' how to solve this

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When I apply f"" string on my text data it procduces the following error. `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`.

The simple code is below, I am providing just one line so that it will save your time. I just want to apply f"" in this way. I know the problem but don't know how to figure it. Thanks

`caption = f"{caption.str.lower().str.rstrip('.')}"`

Comment: if you're asking about pandas string operations, you should include the `pandas` tag, not `tensorflow` or `keras`. also, to get the best help, please always include the code you're working with, an example of your data (at the very least, the types that you're working with), and ideally a full [mre]. See also this guide to creating [minimal examples in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). check out the [ask] guide for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be familiar with the pandas library's [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#string-handling) accessor which make [pandas ports of python string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) available to a Series. But if you're working with python builtin `str` types, you don't need the `.str` accessor. Simply call:

```py
caption = f"{caption.lower().rstrip('.')}"
```

See the [python builtin types docs on string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for more info.

Comment: Thanks it helped me, How can I split this string line by line, I mean how to make this code `caption = f"{caption.lower().rstrip('.')}"` to split my string line by line.

Comment: This `caption` is panda dataframe, if there is any solution to split this `caption` dataframe by rows.

Comment: so - if it's a pandas dataframe then you *should* use .str methods, but don't try to include it in a format string group. just use `caption.str.lower().str.rstrip(".")`. no need to put the series into a `f"{}"`, which would force the series into a python string.

Comment: if you're running into the error in your question, you may have converted your dataframe/series into a python string in an  earlier step. So you may need to go back and make sure your `caption` object stays as a pandas object. Generally, don't force your pandas object to go through python string formatting e.g. with `f"{pandas_obj}"` or `"{}".format(pandas_obj)` unless you know you want to turn the pandas object into a single python string.